# How can I dock the button to jQueryUI dialog bottom as the dialog inner content increases?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

**UPDATE:** Sorry I make this question to complex.

**What I want to ask is that how can I "fix" the buttons' position to the bottom of the jQueryUI dialog as the dialog height grow's larger.**

I have a jQueryUI dialog as follow:

```
<head>
$(function(){
    $("#ChooseStoryCategory").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: "Upload",
        height: 600,
        width: 500,
        modal: true
    }); 
});
</head>
```

And I add two buttons in the dialog and I always want to put them at the `bottom of the dialog`. Here is the code:

```
<body>
<div id= "ChooseStoryCategory">
    <div id="storyCategory"></div>      

    <div><button id="ChooseCategory"><img src= "../pic/chooseOk.png"/></button></div>
    <div><button id="CategoryCancel"><img src= "../pic/close.png"/></button></div>
</div>
</body>
```

css setting:

```
#ChooseCategory{
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    top: 85%;
    bottom: 0;

}

#CategoryCancel{
    position: absolute;
    left: 70%;
    top: 85%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

But I will always increase element inside the dialog like this:

```
for(multiple times)://pseudocode
var categoryName= "PressNum1";
var value= 3;
var $btn= $('<button/>').text(categoryName).width(400).height(80);
$btn.bind('click', function(){console.log(value)});
$("#storyCategory").append($btn);
```

As the added buttons increase, their position will exceed the two buttons(`ChooseCategory` and `CategoryCancel`). How can I dock the two buttons to the bottom of the jQueryUI dialog?

I have tried to get the initial top position of the two buttons. As each button is added to the dialog, I just change the position of the `two buttons`.

```
$("#CategoryCancel").css("height") = $("#ChooseStoryCategory").css("height") * 0.85 + $btn.css("height");
```

But

```
$("#ChooseStoryCategory").css("height") * 0.85 + $btn.css("height");
```

didn't add the `px`, it just combines the number and string...

Is there any simple alternative approach to dock the two buttons at the bottom of the jqueryUI dialog?

Comment: Somebody helps!  Do I describe the problem too complex? It's really a simple question. Please help! Thank you, guys...

Comment: I've made a fiddle from your code, however i don't understand what is the actual problem :/ take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/uqvYh/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why dont you use the `buttons` option?

```
$( "#ChooseStoryCategory" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  title: "Upload",
  height: 600,
  width: 500,
  modal: true
  buttons: {
    "Choose category": function() {
      // Do something
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    },
    Cancel: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
  }
});
```

Check out the examples within jquery-ui's page: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ or check out the API documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons

Here's the jsFeedle: http://jsfiddle.net/6gb4v/ (Took @rusln fiddle and started from there).

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. What I want to ask is that
how can I "fix" the buttons' position to the bottom of the jQueryUI dialog as the dialog height grows larger.

Comment: @stallman The buttons option already fix the buttons to the bottom no matter the content's / dialog's height. Now if what you want is that the modal dynamically grows with its content and the buttons stay fixed to the bottom keep using the buttons option, but set the height to "auto" example: http://jsfiddle.net/filistea/Lp766/